# How to redirect to app from WebBrowser in Expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo, deep-linking

I am currently working on a project on Android using the Expo client for react native. I am trying to open a webpage using WebBrowser, passing my app development URI to the website. The website basically just redirects to the given URI after 5 seconds. However it never seems to open anything. I've used almost the exact same code as here: https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-webbrowser-redirect. When I load this project into expo and run, it redirects fine. However, when I copy the code for the website and app into my own project, website opens and displays, but redirect does nothing. It just stays there. Here is the code for opening the browser.

```
_openBrowserAsync = async () => {
  try {
    this._addLinkingListener();
    let result = await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(
    'https://wexley-auth.firebaseapp.com/?linkingUri=exp://192.168.1.2:19000'
    );
    this._removeLinkingListener();
    this.setState({ result });
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error);
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

The linking listener never fires the callback which should dismiss the browser. My app URI should be exp://192.168.1.2:19000 as expo developer tools shows me this when I connect over LAN. Ive also tried using Linking.makeUrl() instead of sending URI in string manually. Neither method works for me. Relevant website code:

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    var baseUri='';

    // Take the uri from the params
    var qs = decodeURIComponent(document.location.search);
    if (qs) {
      baseUri = qs.split('?linkingUri=')[1];
    }

    var redirectInterval = setInterval(function() {
      var countdown = document.querySelector('.countdown');
      var t = parseInt(countdown.innerText, 10);
      t -= 1;
      if (t === 0) {
        clearInterval(redirectInterval);
        window.location.href = baseUri;
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
```

Am I missing a step? Do I need to setup a scheme for opening my app or should this work out of the box? Am I using the wrong URI? I noticed that in the example code, the app.json has the following fields that my app.json doesn't have:

```
"scheme": "expo.examples.with-webbrowser-redirect",
"platforms": [
  "android",
  "ios"
]
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution for this?